# How does my local HOSTS file resolve but IP will not

Tags: dns, hosts

I'm in the process of launching a new website. I migrated all the code to the new server. The admin at the new host told me that I have to add an entry to my hosts file and then I will be able to see the website. So essentially he had me add:

```
111.222.3333.4444 example.com www.example.com
```

These are example, but after doing this, it worked. My question is, is how? If I visit the IP directly in my browser I get a 403 Forbidden error. Does the host have a way to resolve this IP to a location on their server if resolved from a domain name? I'm just confused as to how this works. I understand that by changing the IP address I can get the domain name to resolve to any IP, but I'm wondering why, on the hosts end, does this now resolve this way, but not by typing in the IP directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Does the host have a way to resolve this IP to a location on their
>   server if resolved from a domain name?

Not exactly. Your browser, when sending the request to the IP address, will send one important piece of information called 'Host header', that is the actual host name as you typed in your browser.

You usually can not open the website just by entering the IP address in your browser's address bar because web servers (and possibly many other network components that are between you and the web server) often do not host only one web site on that IP address so they rely on exact domain name typed in address bar to serve the right content.

You can test this by using one of the browser add-ons that allow you to add your own headers. Add header named 'Host' with the value 'example.com' and with that try to open your site by typing only provided IP address.